# Examples of multiple induction

Tags: examples, induction

It is easy to find/construct cases that can be proven by nested induction, i.e., some variation of the theme to prove the statement $P(m, n)$ you prove $P(1, n)$ by induction as a base case for $m$, and given $P(m,n)$ you prove $P(m + 1, n)$.

I'm interested in cases in which it is natural/simpler to define some order between pairs $(m, n)$ and the induction proof is along this order, not two nested inductions as outlined above.

Comment: Have you got any example in mind?

Comment: In a sense a lot of research works like this - define a complexity and show you can always reduce it. What aspect about education are you interested in?

Comment: The most basic non-trivial example: the termination of the recursive definition of the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Comment: @dtldarek why don't you make that an answer?  In general, this is a question of mine: why do people post potential answers as comments?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but what about back and forth arguments?